# Combine a string and an array with JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to combine a string and an array with JSON. No success, so far.

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$url = ‘example.com’;
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$regex = '/list-animal-id">(.+?)</';
$input = ‘testtext';
preg_match_all($regex,$data, $match);
    //var_dump($match);
    //echo  json_encode($match[1]);
$json = array($input, $match[1]);
$json_data = json_encode($json);
echo  $json_data;

?>
```

$match comes back with an array, for instance:

```
"22425229","22493325","22596308","24635614","22202322"
```

The above only creates one instance of the string:

```
["testtext",["22425229","22493325","22596308"......
```

I want to create something like this:

```
"testtext":"22425229", "testtext":"22425230"
```

Thanks,

Comment: You have some bad quotes that are causing syntax errors. What are you editing this with?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking to do is not possible. `[ "testtext":"22425229", "testtext":"22425230" ]` assumes an array in which every key is "testtext". You cannot have an array or object with the same key repeated.

What you can do is create an array of arrays where each item is an associative array (object in JSON):

```
<?php
$url = 'example.com';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$regex = '/list-animal-id">(.+?)</';
$input = 'testtext';
preg_match_all($regex,$data, $match);
    //var_dump($match);
    //echo  json_encode($match[1]);

function outputArray( $value ) {
    global $input;
    return array( $input => $value );
}

$json = array_map( 'outputArray', $match );
$json_data = json_encode($json);
echo  $json_data;

?>
```

Output is: `[{"testtext":"22425229"},{"testtext":"22493325"},{"testtext":"22596308"},{"testtext":"24635614"},{"testtext":"22202322"}]`

Comment: Thanks Jim! works well.  So I guess, my take away from this (I am very new to PHP) is that heavy lifting needs to be done before json.

Answer (score 0):

my solution was wrong and shouldn't stay here confusing others... the right solution can be found in Jims answere...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I couldn't get this one to work, most likely operator error. :)

Comment: ok... you still need you original code including the "preg_match_all" function...

Comment: @bohrsty, this will never work. As I wrote in my answer, you cannot have an array or object in either PHP or JavaScript with the same key repeated multple times. It will simply overwrite the value of that key entry until it gets to the last entry with that specific key. The output would always be `{"testtext":"22202322"}` ("testtext" with the last value). Try your answer with @magicJerk's code to see the result.

Comment: @Jim you are absolutley right, this never will work... it was a long day yesterday... i'll remove my code and reference to your solution...